# How to call wp plugin REST functions without curl?

Tags: rest-api

I'm using the [JSON REST User plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/) which extends [JSON REST Api](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/). I'm sending http data to-from the api up to 4 times back to back in some cases which is dragging network performance.

How can I call

`http://localhost/wp-json/fb_connect?x&y&z`

from php without using curl? (I'll use curl if it makes the most sense)

*the main plugin file, where the fb_connect function is:*

**/wp-content/plugins/json-api-user/controllers/User.php**

```
/*
  Controller name: User
  Controller description: User Registration, Authentication, User Info, User Meta, FB Login, BuddyPress xProfile Fields methods
  Controller Author: Ali Qureshi
  Controller Author Twitter: @parorrey
  Controller Author Website: parorrey.com

*/
class JSON_API_User_Controller {

  /**
     * Returns an Array with registered userid & valid cookie
     * @param String username: username to register
     * @param String email: email address for user registration
     * @param String user_pass: user_pass to be set (optional)
     * @param String display_name: display_name for user
     */   
public function __construct() {
        global $json_api;
        // allow only connection over https. because, well, you care about your passwords and sniffing.
        // turn this sanity-check off if you feel safe inside your localhost or intranet.
        // send an extra POST parameter: insecure=cool
        if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ||
            (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off')) {
            if (empty($_REQUEST['insecure']) || $_REQUEST['insecure'] != 'cool') {
                $json_api->error("SSL is not enabled. Either use _https_ or provide 'insecure' var as insecure=cool to confirm you want to use http protocol.");
            }
        }


    }

public function info(){   

        global $json_api;

        return array(
                "version" => JAU_VERSION                
           );      

      }  

public function register(){

    global $json_api;     


if (!get_option('users_can_register')) {
            $json_api->error("User registration is disabled. Please enable it in Settings > Gereral.");            
        }

   if (!$json_api->query->username) {
            $json_api->error("You must include 'username' var in your request. ");
        }
    else $username = sanitize_user( $json_api->query->username );


  if (!$json_api->query->email) {
            $json_api->error("You must include 'email' var in your request. ");
        }
    else $email = sanitize_email( $json_api->query->email );

 if (!$json_api->query->nonce) {
            $json_api->error("You must include 'nonce' var in your request. Use the 'get_nonce' Core API method. ");
        }
 else $nonce =  sanitize_text_field( $json_api->query->nonce ) ;

 if (!$json_api->query->display_name) {
            $json_api->error("You must include 'display_name' var in your request. ");
        }
    else $display_name = sanitize_text_field( $json_api->query->display_name );

$user_pass = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['user_pass'] );

if ($json_api->query->seconds)  $seconds = (int) $json_api->query->seconds;

        else $seconds = 1209600;//14 days

//Add usernames we don't want used

$invalid_usernames = array( 'admin' );

//Do username validation

$nonce_id = $json_api->get_nonce_id('user', 'register');

 if( !wp_verify_nonce($json_api->query->nonce, $nonce_id) ) {

    $json_api->error("Invalid access, unverifiable 'nonce' value. Use the 'get_nonce' Core API method. ");
        }

 else {

    if ( !validate_username( $username ) || in_array( $username, $invalid_usernames ) ) {

  $json_api->error("Username is invalid.");

        }

    elseif ( username_exists( $username ) ) {

    $json_api->error("Username already exists.");

           }            

    else{


    if ( !is_email( $email ) ) {
     $json_api->error("E-mail address is invalid.");
             }
    elseif (email_exists($email)) {

     $json_api->error("E-mail address is already in use.");

          }         

else {

    //Everything has been validated, proceed with creating the user

//Create the user

if( !isset($_REQUEST['user_pass']) ) {
     $user_pass = wp_generate_password();
     $_REQUEST['user_pass'] = $user_pass;
}

 $_REQUEST['user_login'] = $username;
 $_REQUEST['user_email'] = $email;

$allowed_params = array('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass', 'display_name', 'user_nicename', 'user_url', 'nickname', 'first_name',
                         'last_name', 'description', 'rich_editing', 'user_registered', 'role', 'jabber', 'aim', 'yim',
                         'comment_shortcuts', 'admin_color', 'use_ssl', 'show_admin_bar_front'
                   );


foreach($_REQUEST as $field => $value){

    if( in_array($field, $allowed_params) ) $user[$field] = trim(sanitize_text_field($value));

    }
$user['role'] = get_option('default_role');
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $user );

/*Send e-mail to admin and new user - 
You could create your own e-mail instead of using this function*/

if( isset($_REQUEST['user_pass']) && $_REQUEST['notify']=='no') {
    $notify = '';   
  }elseif($_REQUEST['notify']!='no') $notify = $_REQUEST['notify'];


if($user_id) wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, '',$notify );  


            }
        } 
   }


    $expiration = time() + apply_filters('auth_cookie_expiration', $seconds, $user_id, true);

    $cookie = wp_generate_auth_cookie($user_id, $expiration, 'logged_in');

 return array( 
          "cookie" => $cookie,  
          "user_id" => $user_id 
          );          

  } 

public function get_avatar(){     

        global $json_api;

if (function_exists('bp_is_active')) {  

    if (!$json_api->query->user_id) {
            $json_api->error("You must include 'user_id' var in your request. ");
        }

      if (!$json_api->query->type) {
            $json_api->error("You must include 'type' var in your request. possible values 'full' or 'thumb' ");
        }


$avatar = bp_core_fetch_avatar ( array( 'item_id' => $json_api->query->user_id, 'type' => $json_api->query->type, 'html'=>false ));

        return array('avatar'=>$avatar);    
   } else {

      $json_api->error("You must install and activate BuddyPress plugin to use this method.");

      }

     } 

public function get_userinfo(){   

        global $json_api;

    if (!$json_api->query->user_id) {
            $json_api->error("You must include 'user_id' var in your request. ");
        }

        $user = get_userdata($json_api->query->user_id);

        preg_match('|src="(.+?)"|', get_avatar( $user->ID, 32 ), $avatar);      

        return array(
                "id" => $user->ID,
                //"username" => $user->user_login,
                "nicename" => $user->user_nicename,
                //"email" => $user->user_email,
                "url" => $user->user_url,
                "displayname" => $user->display_name,
                "firstname" => $user->user_firstname,
                "lastname" => $user->last_name,
                "nickname" => $user->nickname,
                "avatar" => $avatar[1]
           );      

      }   

public function retrieve_password(){

    global $wpdb, $json_api, $wp_hasher;  

   if (!$json_api->query->user_login) {

            $json_api->error("You must include 'user_login' var in your request. ");

        }

    $user_login = $json_api->query->user_login;

  if ( strpos( $user_login, '@' ) ) {

        $user_data = get_user_by( 'email', trim( $user_login ) );

        if ( empty( $user_data ) )



     $json_api->error("Your email address not found! ");



    } else {

        $login = trim($user_login);

        $user_data = get_user_by('login', $login);

    }



    // redefining user_login ensures we return the right case in the email

    $user_login = $user_data->user_login;

    $user_email = $user_data->user_email;


    do_action('retrieve_password', $user_login);


    $allow = apply_filters('allow_password_reset', true, $user_data->ID);

    if ( ! $allow )  $json_api->error("password reset not allowed! ");        

    elseif ( is_wp_error($allow) )  $json_api->error("An error occured! "); 



    $key = wp_generate_password( 20, false );

    do_action( 'retrieve_password_key', $user_login, $key );



    if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {

        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/class-phpass.php';

        $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );

    }


    $hashed = time() . ':' . $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $key );

    $wpdb->update( $wpdb->users, array( 'user_activation_key' => $hashed ), array( 'user_login' => $user_login ) ); 

    $message = __('Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:') . "\r\n\r\n";

    $message .= network_home_url( '/' ) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";

    $message .= __('If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.') . "\r\n\r\n";

    $message .= __('To reset your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";

    $message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n";



    if ( is_multisite() )

        $blogname = $GLOBALS['current_site']->site_name;

    else

        $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);



    $title = sprintf( __('[%s] Password Reset'), $blogname );



    $title = apply_filters('retrieve_password_title', $title);

    $message = apply_filters('retrieve_password_message', $message, $key);



    if ( $message && !wp_mail($user_email, $title, $message) )

       $json_api->error("The e-mail could not be sent. Possible reason: your host may have disabled the mail() function...");

    else     

   return array(

    "msg" => 'Link for password reset has been emailed to you. Please check your email.',

          );        

     } 

public function validate_auth_cookie() {

        global $json_api;

        if (!$json_api->query->cookie) {

            $json_api->error("You must include a 'cookie' authentication cookie. Use the `create_auth_cookie` method.");

        }       

        $valid = wp_validate_auth_cookie($json_api->query->cookie, 'logged_in') ? true : false;

        return array(

            "valid" => $valid

        );

    }

public function generate_auth_cookie() {

        global $json_api;

        foreach($_POST as $k=>$val) {
            if (isset($_POST[$k])) {
                $json_api->query->$k = $val;
            }
        }


        if (!$json_api->query->username && !$json_api->query->email) {

            $json_api->error("You must include 'username' or 'email' var in your request to generate cookie.");

        }


        if (!$json_api->query->password) {

            $json_api->error("You must include a 'password' var in your request.");

        }   

        if ($json_api->query->seconds)  $seconds = (int) $json_api->query->seconds;

        else $seconds = 1209600;//14 days

       if ( $json_api->query->email ) {


         if ( is_email(  $json_api->query->email ) ) {
          if( !email_exists( $json_api->query->email))  {
             $json_api->error("email does not exist."); 
              }
         }else  $json_api->error("Invalid email address."); 

        $user_obj = get_user_by( 'email', $json_api->query->email );


        $user = wp_authenticate($user_obj->data->user_login, $json_api->query->password);
    }else {

         $user = wp_authenticate($json_api->query->username, $json_api->query->password);
        }


        if (is_wp_error($user)) {

            $json_api->error("Invalid username/email and/or password.", 'error', '401');

            remove_action('wp_login_failed', $json_api->query->username);

        }


        $expiration = time() + apply_filters('auth_cookie_expiration', $seconds, $user->ID, true);

        $cookie = wp_generate_auth_cookie($user->ID, $expiration, 'logged_in');

        preg_match('|src="(.+?)"|', get_avatar( $user->ID, 512 ), $avatar); 

        return array(
            "cookie" => $cookie,
            "cookie_name" => LOGGED_IN_COOKIE,
            "user" => array(
                "id" => $user->ID,
                "username" => $user->user_login,
                "nicename" => $user->user_nicename,
                "email" => $user->user_email,
                "url" => $user->user_url,
                "registered" => $user->user_registered,
                "displayname" => $user->display_name,
                "firstname" => $user->user_firstname,
                "lastname" => $user->last_name,
                "nickname" => $user->nickname,
                "description" => $user->user_description,
                "capabilities" => $user->wp_capabilities,
                "avatar" => $avatar[1]

            ),
        );
    }

public function get_currentuserinfo() {

        global $json_api;

        if (!$json_api->query->cookie) {

            $json_api->error("You must include a 'cookie' var in your request. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` Auth API method.");

        }

        $user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($json_api->query->cookie, 'logged_in');


        if (!$user_id) {
            $json_api->error("Invalid authentication cookie. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
        }

        $user = get_userdata($user_id);

        preg_match('|src="(.+?)"|', get_avatar( $user->ID, 32 ), $avatar);



        return array(

            "user" => array(

                "id" => $user->ID,

                "username" => $user->user_login,

                "nicename" => $user->user_nicename,

                "email" => $user->user_email,

                "url" => $user->user_url,

                "registered" => $user->user_registered,

                "displayname" => $user->display_name,

                "firstname" => $user->user_firstname,

                "lastname" => $user->last_name,

                "nickname" => $user->nickname,

                "description" => $user->user_description,

                "capabilities" => $user->wp_capabilities,

                "avatar" => $avatar[1]

            )

        );

    }   

public function get_user_meta() {

      global $json_api;

      if (!$json_api->query->cookie) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'cookie' var in your request. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
        }

        $user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($json_api->query->cookie, 'logged_in');

    if (!$user_id)  $json_api->error("Invalid cookie. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");

 $meta_key = sanitize_text_field($json_api->query->meta_key);   


        if($meta_key) $data[$meta_key] = get_user_meta(  $user_id, $meta_key);
        else {
        // Get all user meta data for $user_id
            $meta = get_user_meta( $user_id );

            // Filter out empty meta data
            $data = array_filter( array_map( function( $a ) {
                    return $a[0];
                    }, $meta ) );

         }
//d($data);
       return $data;


      }

public function update_user_meta() {

      global $json_api;

       if (!$json_api->query->cookie) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'cookie' var in your request. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
        }

        $user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($json_api->query->cookie, 'logged_in');

    if (!$user_id)  $json_api->error("Invalid cookie. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");


   if (!$json_api->query->meta_key) $json_api->error("You must include a 'meta_key' var in your request.");

        else $meta_key = $json_api->query->meta_key;    

   if (!$json_api->query->meta_value) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'meta_value' var in your request. You may provide multiple values separated by comma for 'meta_value' var.");
        }
        else $meta_value = sanitize_text_field($json_api->query->meta_value);

  if( strpos($meta_value,',') !== false ) {
        $meta_values = explode(",", $meta_value);
       $meta_values = array_map('trim',$meta_values);

       $data['updated'] = update_user_meta(  $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_values);
       }
 else $data['updated'] = update_user_meta(  $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value); 

       return $data;        

      }

public function delete_user_meta() {

      global $json_api;

       if (!$json_api->query->cookie) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'cookie' var in your request. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
        }

        $user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($json_api->query->cookie, 'logged_in');

    if (!$user_id)  $json_api->error("Invalid cookie. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");


   if (!$json_api->query->meta_key) $json_api->error("You must include a 'meta_key' var in your request.");

        else $meta_key = $json_api->query->meta_key;    

   if (!$json_api->query->meta_value) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'meta_value' var in your request.");
        }
        else $meta_value = sanitize_text_field($json_api->query->meta_value);


        $data['deleted'] = delete_user_meta(  $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value);

       return $data;        

      }

public function update_user_meta_vars() {

      global $json_api; 

      if (!$json_api->query->cookie) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'cookie' var in your request. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
        }

        $user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($json_api->query->cookie, 'logged_in');
//  echo '$user_id: '.$user_id; 

        if (!$user_id) {
            $json_api->error("Invalid cookie. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
        }

    if( sizeof($_REQUEST) <=1) $json_api->error("You must include one or more vars in your request to add or update as user_meta. e.g. 'name', 'website', 'skills'. You must provide multiple meta_key vars in this format: &name=Ali&website=parorrey.com&skills=php,css,js,web design. If any field has the possibility to hold more than one value for any multi-select fields or check boxes, you must provide ending comma even when it has only one value so that it could be added in correct array format to distinguish it from simple string var. e.g. &skills=php,");

//d($_REQUEST);
foreach($_REQUEST as $field => $value){

    if($field=='cookie') continue;

    $field_label = str_replace('_',' ',$field);

    if( strpos($value,',') !== false ) {
        $values = explode(",", $value);
       $values = array_map('trim',$values);
       }
    else $values = trim($value);
    //echo 'field-values: '.$field.'=>'.$value;
    //d($values);

   $result[$field_label]['updated'] =  update_user_meta(  $user_id, $field, $values);

}

     return $result;


  }   

public function xprofile() {

      global $json_api;

if (function_exists('bp_is_active')) {  

      if (!$json_api->query->user_id) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'user_id' var in your request.");
        }
        else $user_id = $json_api->query->user_id;


   if (!$json_api->query->field) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'field' var in your request. Use 'field=default' for all default fields.");
        }
      elseif ($json_api->query->field=='default') {
            $field_label='First Name, Last Name, Bio';/*you should add your own field labels here for quick viewing*/
        }   
        else $field_label = sanitize_text_field($json_api->query->field);   


  $fields = explode(",", $field_label);

  if(is_array($fields)){

      foreach($fields as $k){

          $fields_data[$k] = xprofile_get_field_data( $k, $user_id );

          }

       return $fields_data;


      }

   }

  else {

      $json_api->error("You must install and activate BuddyPress plugin to use this method.");

      }

  }

public function xprofile_update() {

      global $json_api; 

if (function_exists('bp_is_active')) {  

      if (!$json_api->query->cookie) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'cookie' var in your request. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
        }

        $user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($json_api->query->cookie, 'logged_in');
//  echo '$user_id: '.$user_id; 

        if (!$user_id) {
            $json_api->error("Invalid cookie. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
        }


foreach($_REQUEST as $field => $value){

    if($field=='cookie') continue;

    $field_label = str_replace('_',' ',$field);

    if( strpos($value,',') !== false ) {
        $values = explode(",", $value);
       $values = array_map('trim',$values);
       }
    else $values = trim($value);
    //echo 'field-values: '.$field.'=>'.$value;
    //d($values);

  $result[$field_label]['updated'] = xprofile_set_field_data( $field_label,  $user_id, $values, $is_required = true ); 

}

     return $result;
   }

  else {

      $json_api->error("You must install and activate BuddyPress plugin to use this method.");

      }

  }  

public function fb_connect(){

        global $json_api;

        if ($json_api->query->fields) {

            $fields = $json_api->query->fields;

        }else $fields = 'id,name,first_name,last_name,email';

        if ($json_api->query->ssl) {
             $enable_ssl = $json_api->query->ssl;
        }else $enable_ssl = true;

    if (!$json_api->query->access_token) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'access_token' variable. Get the valid access_token for this app from Facebook API.");
        }else{

$url='https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields='.$fields.'&access_token='.$json_api->query->access_token;

    //  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Enable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $enable_ssl);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

    $result = json_decode($result, true);

   if(isset($result["email"])){

            $user_email = $result["email"];
            $email_exists = email_exists($user_email);

            if($email_exists) {
                $user = get_user_by( 'email', $user_email );
              $user_id = $user->ID;
              $user_name = $user->user_login;
             }



            if ( !$user_id && $email_exists == false ) {

              $user_name = strtolower($result['first_name'].'.'.$result['last_name']);

                while(username_exists($user_name)){             
                $i++;
                $user_name = strtolower($result['first_name'].'.'.$result['last_name']).'.'.$i;              

                    }

             $random_password = wp_generate_password( $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false );
               $userdata = array(
                           'user_login'    => $user_name,
                           'user_email'    => $user_email,
                           'user_pass'  => $random_password,
                           'display_name'  => $result["name"],
                           'first_name'  => $result['first_name'],
                           'last_name'  => $result['last_name']
                                     );

                   $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;                
                 if($user_id) $user_account = 'user registered.';

            } else {

                 if($user_id) $user_account = 'user logged in.';
                }

             $expiration = time() + apply_filters('auth_cookie_expiration', 1209600, $user_id, true);
             $cookie = wp_generate_auth_cookie($user_id, $expiration, 'logged_in');

        $response['msg'] = $user_account;
        $response['wp_user_id'] = $user_id;
        $response['cookie'] = $cookie;
        $response['user_login'] = $user_name;   

        }
        else {
            $response['msg'] = "Your 'access_token' did not return email of the user. Without 'email' user can't be logged in or registered. Get user email extended permission while joining the Facebook app.";

            }

    }   

return $response;

      }

public function post_comment(){
   global $json_api;

  if (!$json_api->query->cookie) {
            $json_api->error("You must include a 'cookie' var in your request. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
        }

  $user_id = wp_validate_auth_cookie($json_api->query->cookie, 'logged_in');

        if (!$user_id) {
            $json_api->error("Invalid cookie. Use the `generate_auth_cookie` method.");
        }

 if ( !$json_api->query->post_id ) {
  $json_api->error("No post specified. Include 'post_id' var in your request.");
  } elseif (!$json_api->query->content ) {
  $json_api->error("Please include 'content' var in your request.");
  }

  if (!$json_api->query->comment_status ) {
  $json_api->error("Please include 'comment_status' var in your request. Possible values are '1' (approved) or '0' (not-approved)");
  }else $comment_approved = $json_api->query->comment_status;

$user_info = get_userdata(  $user_id );

 $time = current_time('mysql');
 $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
 $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $data = array(
  'comment_post_ID' => $json_api->query->post_id,
  'comment_author' => $user_info->user_login,
  'comment_author_email' => $user_info->user_email,
  'comment_author_url' => $user_info->user_url,
  'comment_content' => $json_api->query->content,
  'comment_type' => '',
  'comment_parent' => 0,
  'user_id' => $user_info->ID,
  'comment_author_IP' =>  $ip,
  'comment_agent' => $agent,
  'comment_date' => $time,
  'comment_approved' => $comment_approved,
   );

//print_r($data);

 $comment_id = wp_insert_comment($data);

 return array(
             "comment_id" => $comment_id
             );    
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can internally route REST API requests using [`rest_do_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_do_request/) and a [`WP_REST_Request` object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/).

```
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/fb_connect' );
$request->set_param( 'x', true );
// You can also use it this way:
$request['y'] = true;
$request['z'] = true;

$response = rest_do_request( $request );
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to a server configuration - if you have enabled "allow_url_fopen" in your php.ini you could simply open the URLs using fopen, but from your example using this method might cause some issues with SSL so you may want to look here for how to deal with that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820376/fopen-accept-self-signed-certificate